# How to translate collections in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using the [pluck method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-pluck) to retrieve values. How can I translate these values? (these values are options for a selection input field)

```
$relationtypes = Relationtype::pluck('name', 'id');
```

My relationtypes are: supplier, customer, etc.

Comment: Translate them into what?

Comment: e.g. when local is set to 'nl', it should translate the values in dutch with the funtion trans('label.customer')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also found a more convenient solution:

```
$relationtypes = RelationType::pluck('name', 'id')->map(function ($item, $key) {
    return trans('labels.' . $item . '');
});
```

Passing this to your view, you can use:

```
{!! Form::select('relationtypes[]', $relationtypes, 
    isset($relation) ? $relation->relationtypes->pluck('id')->toArray() : 0, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

Hope this helps other people!

Answer (score 1):

Your controller method may look like:

```
public function index () {
  $relationtypes = Relationtype::pluck('name', 'id');

  // A better place for this might be a middleware
  App::setlocale('your-locale'); 

  return view('relationtypes.index, compact('relationtypes'));
}
```

In your view iterate over them:

```
<select>
   @foreach (types as type)
     <option value="{{ type.id }}">{{ trans(type.name) }}</option>
   @endforeach
</select>
```

If you want to translate the values using the `trans` function you'll need to have beforehand the values in `resources\lang\<locale>\<file>.php`

For example, lets image the values from your database are:

```
| id | name       |
|----|------------|
| 1  | slug-one   |
| 2  | slug-two   |
| 3  | slug-three |
```

Then in `resources\lang\nl\slugs.php`

```
return [
  'slug-one' => 'whatever translation for slug-on in nl',
  // ...
];
```

This approach is good for non dynamic values, if your values are dynamic the translation probably must be in some db field like: `name_nl`, `name_en` maybe?

But there are lots of packages for this problem already.

Answer (score 1):

We can create custom Collection method.

```php
Collection::macro('translate', function ($prefix) {
    return $this->map(function ($item) use ($prefix) {
        return trans($prefix . $item);
    });
});
```

in AppServiceProvider.

And usage:

```php
Model::pluck('code_name', 'id')->translate('system.code.')->implode(',');
```