# Laravel 5.5, Collections and Localization

Tags: php, laravel, collections, localization, pluck

This question is a follow-up/attempt to implement the answer from a [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41174623/how-to-translate-collections-in-laravel-5).

My attempt to pluck values from a collection and apply the current localization is as follows:

```
$prefix_array = ['' => trans('registration.prefixes.select')] +
    $prefixes->pluck('prefix', 'prefix')->map(function($item, $key) {
        return trans('messages.fields.prefixes.'.$item);
    })->toArray();
```

However, this produces an array with values like:

```
"Mrs." => "messages.fields.prefixes.Mrs."
```

Instead of:

```
"Mrs." => "Sra."   // eg: shortened Senora for Spanish translation
```

The localization path (messages.fields.prefixes.XYZ) is correct and references to it in other places displays as expected.

Comment: It may be trailing dot (period) is confusing the localisation. You may need to have your translation key as just *'mrs' => 'Mrs.'*

Comment: Turns out, you are absolutely right, Jason.  If you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be trailing dot (period) is confusing the localisation. You may need to have your translation key as just *'mrs' => 'Mrs.'*